# Newtonsoft JSON Collection of Interfaces Serialization error

Tags: c#, json, serialization, interface, json.net

I am using C# .NET 4.0, Newtonsoft JSON 4.5.0.

```
public class Recipe
{
   [JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]
   public List<IFood> Foods{ get; set; }
   ...
 }
```

I want to serialize and deserialize this Recipe object. If I serialize and deserialize the object during application lifetime this succeeds, but if I serialize the object, exit application and then deserialize it then it throws an exception, that it cannot instantiate IFood (since it is an interface).

**The problem is that it does not serialize the implementation of interface.**

*"$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[NSM.Shared.Models.IFood, NSMShared]], mscorlib"*

I tried using TypeNameHandling.Object and Array and Auto, but it didn't help. Is there any way to serialize it properly? Or at least to define the class mapping before deserializing?

**EDIT:**
I am using JSON coupled with Hammock ( http://code.google.com/p/relax-net/ ), C# driver for CouchDB, which internally serializes and deserializes objects. As mentioned the problem is that it does not serialize the interface implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the key, you have to add this property, as it defines how the items in a collection are handled.

**[JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]**

```
public class Recipe
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
    public List<IFood> Foods{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Comment: ...which of course doesn't work if Foods isn't initialized/is empty.