# Easiest way to serialize and deserialize a JSON class that has interface properties?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a

```
class Product
{
    public IComponent[] components;
}
```

What would be the easiest way to deserialize a Product object from some JSON description like

```
{
    "components": [
        {"type":"ComponentA", "key":value}
        {"type":"ComponentB", "key":value}
    ]
}
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Newtonsoft JSON Collection of Interfaces Serialization error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325067/newtonsoft-json-collection-of-interfaces-serialization-error)

Answer (score 2):

Use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

or use `JavaScriptSerializer`

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(product);
```

---

And the reverse operation

```
var product = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(json)
```

or

```
var product = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Product>(json)
```